# Don't receive nested XML nodes from SOAP Web Service using ksoap2

Tags: android, xml, nested, ksoap2

ciao everybody,
I am becoming stupid about this question. I hope someone can help me!! 
I searched in the web for a solution, but everiting I found doesn't work for me. This is the scenario:
I am trying to make a request to a .net ws. The request is simple, but the response is the nested 2 level XML structure that follows:

```
<soap:Body>
    <ProgettoResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <ProgettoResult xmlns="">
        <Success>boolean</Success>
        <Message>string</Message>
        <Progetto>
          <Titolo>string</Titolo>
          <Descrizione>string</Descrizione>
        </Progetto>
      </ProgettoResult>
    </ProgettoResponse>
  </soap:Body>
```

but the response I receive from WS is always: 
    anyType {Success=true; Message=OK; Progetto=anyType{};}

this situation is confirmed by logcat

The  node is always empty. Obviusly I am shure that the WS, invoked with the same parameters sends a complete structure (via a web application and via ad app i-phone).

I am using ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.0-jar-with-dependencies in android 2.1  / 2.2 environment.

This is the class that I use to invoke ws:

```
package feronia.culturando.android;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;


public class webService 
{
    public final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Progetto";
public  final String METHOD_NAME = "Progetto"; 
public  final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
public  final String URL = "http://www.feronia.it/intra/webservice/wsCulturando.asmx";

    public webService() 
    { 
    }

    public String Call(String a,int b)
    {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();
                            pi.setName("a");
                    pi.setValue(a);
                    pi.setType(String.class);
                    request.addProperty(pi);
                    pi=new PropertyInfo();
                    pi.setName("b");
                    pi.setValue(b);
                    pi.setType(Integer.class);
                    request.addProperty(pi);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);

            envelope.dotNet = true;         
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "ProgettoResult", new ProgettoResult().getClass());
            envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "Progetto", new Progetto().getClass());


            HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            SoapObject response=null;

            String totalCount = "";
            try
            {
                    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                    response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
                    //totalCount = response.getPropertyAsString("Progetto").toString();     
                    //totalCount = response.toString();
                    //Progetto prog = response.getProgetto();
                    totalCount =  response.toString();
                    ////////////Progetto prog = (Progetto) response.getProperty(3);
                    //////////////totalCount = prog.toString();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                     e.printStackTrace();
            }


            //String totalCount = response.getProperty("Success").toString();
            //Object totalCount = response.getProperty(Progetto.class);



            //Object resultData = (SoapObject)response.getProperty(2);

            return "risposta dal WS = " + totalCount;
    }


}
```

and these are the classes for ProgettoResult and Progetto

```
package feronia.culturando.android;

import java.util.Hashtable;

import org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;

public class ProgettoResult implements KvmSerializable {


    private String          pSuccess;
    private String          pMessage;
    private Progetto        pProgetto;

    public Progetto getProgetto()
    {
            return pProgetto;
    }

    public void setProgetto(Progetto Progetto)
    {
            this.pProgetto = Progetto;
    }

    public ProgettoResult()
    {
            this.setSuccess("");
            this.setMessage("");
    }

    public ProgettoResult(String Success, String Message)
    {
            this.setSuccess(Success);
            this.setMessage(Message);
    }

    public Object getProperty(int arg0)
    {
            switch(arg0)
            {
            case 0:
                    return this.getSuccess();
            case 1:
                    return this.getMessage();
            case 2:
                    return this.getProgetto();
            }
            return null;
    }


    public int getPropertyCount()
    {
            return 3;
    }

    public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) 
    {
            switch(index)
            {
            case 0:
                    info.name="Success";
                    info.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                    break;
            case 1:
                    info.name="Message";
                    info.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                    break;
            case 2:
                    info.name="Progetto";
                    info.type=Progetto.class;
                    break;
            default:
                    break;
            }
    }


    public void setProperty(int index, Object value) 
    {
            switch(index)
            {
            case 0:
                    this.setSuccess(value.toString());
                    break;
            case 1:
                    this.setMessage(value.toString());
                    break;
            case 2:
                    this.setProgetto((Progetto)value);
                    break;
            default:
                    break;
            }
    }
    /*********** GET - SET   *****************/

    public void setSuccess(String Success)
    {
            this.pSuccess = Success;
    }

    public String getSuccess()
    {
            return pSuccess;
    }

    public void setMessage(String Message)
    {
            this.pMessage = Message;
    }

    public String getMessage()
    {
            return pMessage;
    }
}
```

and

```
package feronia.culturando.android;

import java.util.Hashtable;

import org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;

public class Progetto implements KvmSerializable{

    private String pTitolo;
    private String pDescrizione;

    public Progetto()
    {
            this.setTitolo("");
            this.setDescrizione("");
    }

    public Progetto(String t,String d)
    {
            this.setTitolo(t);
            this.setDescrizione(d);
    }

    public Object getProperty(int index) 
    {
            switch(index)
            {
            case 0:
                    return this.getTitolo();
            case 1:
                    return this.getDescrizione();
            }
            return null;
    }


    public int getPropertyCount() 
    {
            return 2;
    }


    public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) 
    {
            switch(index)
            {
            case 0:
                    info.name="Titolo";
                    info.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                    break;
            case 1:
                    info.name="Descrizione";
                    info.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                    break;
            default: 
                    break;
            }
    }


    public void setProperty(int index, Object value) 
    {
            switch(index)
            {
            case 0:
                    this.setTitolo(value.toString());
                    break;
            case 1:
                    this.setDescrizione(value.toString());
                    break;
            default: 
                    break;
            }
    }

    /*********** GET - SET   *****************/

    public void setTitolo(String Titolo)
    {
            this.pTitolo = Titolo;
    }


    public String getTitolo()
    {
            return pTitolo;
    }

    public void setDescrizione(String Descrizione)
    {
            this.pDescrizione = Descrizione;
    }

    public String getDescrizione()
    {
            return pDescrizione;
    }
}
```

is there anybody who can tell me where is the mistake???  Please help me if You can!!!

================================================================================

thank You very much himanshu and shadesco for your interest to my question!! here is the code of my activity class where is the calling funcion.
string a of the calling is not significant in this moment (not yet implemented the controls upon it: I pass a not significant string), while int b is simply che code of the project (progetto = 2) whose data are requested to web service.

the request:

```
<soap:Body>
    <Progetto xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <Guid>string</Guid>
      <Id_Progetto>int</Id_Progetto>
    </Progetto>
</soap:Body>
```

the code of the calling class: consider that I can see correctly the (wrong) response on the emulator

```
package feronia.culturando.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Presentazione extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.presentazione);


    webService cs=new webService();

    String appo=cs.Call("oi", 2);

    TextView pres_prog = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pres_prog);

    pres_prog.setText(Html.fromHtml(appo));
}

}
```

I don't believe it is important, but the complete response of the method is:

```
<soap:Body>
<ProgettoResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <ProgettoResult xmlns="">
    <Success>boolean</Success>
    <Message>string</Message>
    <Progetto>
      <Titolo>string</Titolo>
      <Descrizione>string</Descrizione>
      <Immagini>
        <Immagine xsi:nil="true" />
        <Immagine xsi:nil="true" />
      </Immagini>
    </Progetto>
  </ProgettoResult>
</ProgettoResponse>
```

there is another block 
     
but requesting progetto = 2 this section of the response is not present (the project has no images associated and the tag

```
<Immagini />
```

is not generated. I am trying to go on step by step...

Comment: Where's your activity class? Post the code of that class.

Comment: @Franco what are : String a,int b for? are they related to the request? if yes, post the soap xml of the request to understand better what you are sending

Comment: @Franco Also, how are you calling function "Call(String a,int b)" , show some code

Comment: @Franco ok so guid is not significant now... well, Progetto is an object, and ur returning "totalCount =  response.toString();". OK try 3 things: 1- instead of returning toString() do "return envelope.getResponse();" and see what it gives u. 2- before the "try" do httpTransport.debug = true, then inside the try System.out.println("requestDump is :"+httpTransport.requestDump);
System.out.println("responseDump is :"+httpTransport.responseDump); and see wht it gives in logcat. 3- try sending the same request using soapUI (sourceforge.net/projects/soapui) and see what the response should look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah Franco instead of keeping writing my comments above, i will write it here.

Well the Structure of your request/response is accurate.
however the response has:

```
<ProgettoResult xmlns="">
 <Success>boolean</Success>
 <Message>string</Message>
 <Progetto>
  <Titolo>string</Titolo>
  <Descrizione>string</Descrizione>
  <Immagini>
    <Immagine xsi:nil="true" />
    <Immagine xsi:nil="true" />
  </Immagini>
 </Progetto>
```

which means Object Progetto requires a parameter Immagini ( it is not obvious here, but i think it is a complex type ie object) BUT, it allows its inside parameters to be **NULL, ie**

```
<Immagine xsi:nil="true" />
<Immagine xsi:nil="true" />
```

**-->nil="true"** ... so what that means is that Immagini can be a sort of "empty" object. So, you need to create a class for it implementing kvm serializable:

```
 public class Immagini implements KvmSerializable{
 //implement the overriden methods just like you did to Progetto
 }
```

And thent you still need to reference it in the Progetto class. So you need to put a reference for Immagini:

```
public class Progetto implements KvmSerializable{

private String pTitolo;
private String pDescrizione;
private Immagini immagini;

public Progetto()
{
        this.setTitolo("");
        this.setDescrizione("");
       //Say put it null
       immagini = null;
}
//continue the rest of the code
```

So what that means, is your response which Progetto requires **THREE** attributes (**Titolo,Descrizione,Immagini**):

```
 <Progetto>
  <Titolo>string</Titolo>
  <Descrizione>string</Descrizione>
  <Immagini>
    <Immagine xsi:nil="true" />
    <Immagine xsi:nil="true" />
  </Immagini>
 </Progetto>
```

You now have created a reference for all 3 of them. It is most probably that the response was requiring **3** property count, but you were giving only **2** thus it couldn't build an appropriate array for it, it build an empty one **Progetto=anyType{}**

let me know if this works.

Comment: Just a doubt: due to the fact that in this situation Immagini is null, I created public class Immagini implements KvmSerializable AS IF Imagini was a simple string. In effect it is (from wsdl) a  type="ArrayOfImmagine" where Immagine is a coplex type composed by 2 strings: dida and path. If You think it is important in this phase, i will try ti build the right classes for Immagini and Immagine, but  I think it is a bit too hard for my actual level.. I need a bit of time to find the right way to do it (this is why i was trying to test ws in a situation without images)

Comment: @Franco listen, try to remove (comment out) these 2 lines: envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "ProgettoResult", new ProgettoResult().getClass());
            envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "Progetto", new Progetto().getClass());   Maybe this mapping of Progetto is different that what you are supposed to send (1 string, 1 int)..your proGetto class which you are mapping is for the response not the request. just comment out these two lines and check if anything changes

Comment: nothing..I did what You suggest, but nothing happens..I tried to do also the opposite: adding  envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "Immagini", new Immagini().getClass()); (I forgot to add this when I added the new class)..I am beginning to hate android :-(

Comment: just a thing: I often found in the examples that in the class for kvmserialization, the basic methods (getPropertyCount, getPropertyInfo, etc.) are declared @override, but if I try to do this, I always get an error by eclipse "the method xxx of type yyy must override a superclass method"..is it regular?

Comment: @Franco take it easy bro, ksoap2 needs patience..It took me some time first time i used it, but ur doing a good job! now do this: instead of info.type=Progetto.class;use info.type=PropertyInfo.OBJECT_CLASS;

Comment: @Franco about the @ override, when u write implements kvmSerializable, eclipse should either ask u/ or automatically override this class's methods.. I remember i had issues with a version of ksoap2 so i used version 2.4 (http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/downloads/detail?name=ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar&can=2&q=) try using this one . Also try using :AndroidHttpTransport  instead of HttpTransportSE . you have to try stuff to find where the problem is happening

Comment: I see this notice over this box: "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?" I donn't know how this chat works: I thik there are about 6 hours of difference beetwneen yoy an me..So I prefer to create another answer..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ProgettoResult pr = null;
try {
    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    pr = (ProgettoResult)envelope.getResponse();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What is `totalCount` ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I always put the same variable name in the getPropertyInfo method, I mean:

you have

```
...
case 0:
    info.name="Success";
    info.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
    break;
...
```

but the variable is named

```
private String pSuccess;
```

maybe using the same name:

```
...
case 0:
    info.name="pSuccess";
    info.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
    break;
...
```